# ¿Cómo modificar valor de propiedad en un JSON SQLSERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, transact-sql

Tengo un objeto JSON y dentro de este tengo una lista, y en esta lista necesitó editar el valor de una propiedad en todas sus posiciones.

El nombre de la propiedad es  `CitationFindingsFormDetail`  la cual es una lista y dentro necesitó modificar la propiedad  `IdCitationFindingsForm`

Entonces dentro de la lista   todos los valores `IdCitationFindingsForm = @identificador`
Así lo cambio en la posición 0 pero necesitó cambiarlo en todas las posiciones

```
SET @itemsJson= JSON_MODIFY(@itemsJson,'$.CitationFindingsFormDetail[0].IdCitationFindingsForm',@identificador)
```

JSON:

```
{"Id":0,
"IdUser":21,
"IdState":1,
"DateCreate":"2022-06-16T08:39:38.9789071-04:00",
"IdUserCreate":0,
"DateUpdate":"2022-06-16T08:39:38.9789145-04:00",
"IdUserUpdate":0,
"CitationFindingsFormDetail":
[{"IdDetail":0,
"IdCitationFindingsForm":0,
"IdStateDetail":1,
"Ask":"Selección Única",
"ResponseType":false,
"IsToShow":true,
"Mandatory":true,
"IsConditionAsk":true,
"IdConditionAsk":0,
"IsConditionResponse":true,
"IdConditionResponse":0,"PositionDetail":1},
{"IdDetail":0,
"IdCitationFindingsForm":0,
"IdStateDetail":1,
"Ask":"Selección Única",
"ResponseType":false,
"IsToShow":true,
"Mandatory":false,
"IsConditionAsk":false,
"IdConditionAsk":0,
"IsConditionResponse":false,
"IdConditionResponse":0,"PositionDetail":2}]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con:

```sql
DECLARE @tablamodificada TABLE (IdCitationFindingsForm INT(11))

INSERT INTO @tablamodificada(IdCitationFindingsForm) 
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@itemsJso, '$.CitationFindingsFormDetail') 
WITH (IdCitationFindingsForm INT(11))

UPDATE @tablamodificada
SET IdCitationFindingsForm = @identificador
```

> Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383827/sql-server-json-modify-how-to-update-all